# jQuery ajax error when sending data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to debug an error which is coming up when u run the following code. The ajax call simply carries a variable `destroy` which is a `String`. However, I am getting an error `alert(xhr.status);` which is return 0 and statusText is returning "error". Can anyone see a problem in this?

The new updated code is:

```
function logout() {
var destroy = "session_destroy"
FB.logout(function(response) {
    $.post("setUser.php", { destroy: destroy }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
        window.location.href = "signup.php";
    })
    .fail(function() { 
        alert("error"); 
    })
    .always(function() { 
        alert("finished"); 
    });
}
```

Note: This ajax calls intends to destory session whose code exists in `setUser.php`

Comment: this `"destroy="+destroy` change to this and try: {"destroy":destroy}

Comment: @Jai I tried again, still no change.

Comment: @Namit: What is the `String`? Sometimes error also occurs when the String is not `HTML`-friendly. Also check the spellings and paths of your files. There's a capital `U` in `setUser` I guess.

Comment: Are you sure the filename is correct, and that the file is in the same folder etc. Also, doing an ajax request just to redirect as soon it's finished kind of defeats the purpose, and a regular form submit could have handled this just fine ?

Comment: (1) you can use JSON.stringify to make sure your destroy data does not mess up the request, and (2) you can use chrome with debug and check if the request is sent and the response is an error or it doesn't even get sent at all

Comment: The file name is correct as I am using the same file for another Ajax call. I need to redirect because I am using facebook connect and this code essentially runs when a user wants to logout. Facebook JS makes you use FB.logout to destroy the facebook session, and in this case i am destroying the self created sessions and redirecting.

Comment: The third argument passed to the `error` callback is the error thrown; might be a good idea to output that as well.

Comment: What are you giving back from setUser.php? If it does not conform for example utf8, you might end up with an error as well.

Comment: @kms: just to be sure i am simply echoing `check` which still gives this error.

Comment: the headers of the php script must be set correctly

Comment: @Tivie, I am not using any headers in the PHP file.

Comment: @Namit let's continue this in the chat... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24279/jquery-ajax-error-when-sending-data

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code. What is it the response setUser.php is giving you?

NOTE: 
To see what is being logged in CHrome or IE >9 press F12, and go to console.

But why aren't you using the shorthand version?

```
$.post("setUser.php", { destroy: destroy }, function (data) {
    alert(data);
    window.location.href = "signup.php";
})
 .fail(function(e, status, error) { 
     console.log(e);
     console.log(status);
     console.log(error);
     alert(error);
 })
 .always(function() { 
     alert("finished"); 
 });
```

[**DOCS**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Use the dev tools with this code and tell me what is outputed

Comment: If you mean the console output in the browser. Then nothing is outputted there.